# Error Message: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to declare some properties using hooks, and then update using function

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const [state, setState] = useState({
    drivingStatus: false, 
    currentWindow: 'driver'
});

export const drivingRequest = () => {
    setState({...state, drivingStatus: state.drivingStatus ? false : true});
}

export const switchWindow = () => {
    setState({...state, currentWindow: state.currentWindow == 'driver' ? 'user' : 'driver'});
}
```

Here's the error message I got:

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This
could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

EDITED

This is a config file, accessible in several other files

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const [state, setState] = useState({
    drivingStatus: false, 
    currentWindow: 'driver'
});

export const drivingRequest = () => {
    setState({...state, drivingStatus: state.drivingStatus ? false : true});
}

export const switchWindow = () => {
    setState({...state, currentWindow: state.currentWindow == 'driver' ? 'user' : 'driver'});
}


export const userFirstName = 'xxxx';

export const userLastName = 'xxxx';

export const userCountry = '';

export const userCountryStatus = 'active';

export const userRegion = ''; 

export const userIso = ''; 

export const userIso3 = ''; 

export const userLocale = 'en-US'; 

export const userLanguage = '';

export const userWalletBalance = 0000;

export const userNotification = 0000;

export const userAccountType = 'driver';

export const userCurrentWindow = state.currentWindow;

export const userDriverID = '';

export const userDrivingStatus = state.drivingStatus;

export const userAverageRating = (userAccountType == 'driver' && userCurrentWindow == 'driver') ? 3.9 : 2.8;
```

And here is a sample file where config.js is imported

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Pressable, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { DrawerContentScrollView, DrawerItemList } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { userFirstName, userLastName, userAverageRating, userWalletBalance, userIso3, userNotification, userCurrentWindow, userAccountType, userDriverID, userDrivingStatus, drivingRequest, switchWindow } from './userAuth';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';

const CustomDrawer = (props) => {

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <View>
        <Text>User first name: {userFirstName}</Text>
        ....
    </View>
  )
}

export default CustomDrawer;
```

Comment: you're breaking the rules of hooks. Read here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: I know I'm not getting it right, which is why I'm here. I have wrap the hook in react render format, but can't seem to effect the updates from the other functions. If can guide me through, I will appreciate it.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the entire file contents? The answer depends on if you're using Class Components or Function Components

Comment: You can't define and use a state outside of a component. You need to either create a function component with no HTML output in the return (Empty Div) or integrate the state setting into your main components.